# Re-arranging words in a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, proxy, python-requests, list-comprehension

So I was writing a python script that includes user pass proxies when I realized that the proxys that I bought come in IP:Port:User:Pass format and python requests module needs them to be in User:pass@Ip:port, It's a pain in the ass to change this manually and impossible if I'm using 1000's of proxies. So I was wondering if there's anyway I can change the proxy from IP:Port:User:Pass to the user:pass@IP:port format in python. I stored the proxies in a list like so

```
proxy_list = ['https':'IP:Port:User:Pass', 'IP:Port:User:Pass'...]
```

Comment: We need the correct format, because ```:``` causes an error

Comment: your two items in the list are not in the same format, which is the correct format. and also give as a coded example of what you want

Comment: yea sorry about that the correct format is



`proxy_list = ['IP:Port:User:Pass', 'IP:Port:User:Pass'...]`

Comment: you haven't supplied a coded example of what you want it to look like, it would be helpful if you could

Comment: What I'm looking for is to rearrange the IP:port:user:pass to a different format. That format would be User:Pass@IP:Port. So in code the proxy format I want would look like this.  
`proxy_list = ['fdjklsdf:fdshklsfdx@star-ca-sticky.simpleproxies.io:12345']`

and the one I have right now would look like this:

`proxy_list = ['star-ca-sticky.simpleproxies.io:12345:fddsfsd:fdssfdds']`

Comment: just a note edit the question instead of adding comments, makes it easier to read

Comment: see my answer also

Comment: Yea, I'm sorry  I'm new to python and stackoverflow I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
proxy_list = ['IP:Port:User:Pass', 'IP:Port:User:Pass']

proxy_list = [i.split(':')[2]+':'+i.split(':')[3]+'@'+i.split(':')[0]+':'+i.split(':')[1] for i in proxy_list]
print(proxy_list)

>>> ['User:Pass@IP:Port', 'User:Pass@IP:Port']
```